# Restriciting Number of Characters entered into SQLite3

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

I'm trying to create an SQL database with the following fields:

```
connection= sqlite3.connect('Main Database')
crsr = connection.cursor()
#Creates a table for the teacher data if no table is found on the system
crsr.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Teacher_Table(Teacher_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                    TFirst_Name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
                    TLast_Name VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
                    Gender CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
                    Home_Address VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
                    Contact_Number VARCHAR (14) NOT NULL);""")
connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

But when I input values, the gender field accepts more than one value
[Database View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxJGQ.png)

How can I make sure it only accepts one character for that field

Comment: SqlLite ignores the length constraints https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: What do you want to happen if an attempt is made to insert more than one character: get an error or silently truncate to one character?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I make sure it only accepts one character for that field

SQLite does *not* check the length constraints defined at type level, as is specified in the [documentation on types](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity_name_examples):

> (...) Note that **numeric arguments in parentheses** that following the type name (ex: "`VARCHAR(255)`") **are ignored** by SQLite - SQLite does **not impose any length restrictions** (other than the large global `SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH` limit) on the length of strings, BLOBs or numeric values.

So you can not *enforce* this at the database level. You will thus need to enforce this through your views, etc.

We can however, like [@Ilja Everilä](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53239175/restriciting-number-of-characters-entered-into-sqlite3/53239223#comment93364388_53239223) says, use a [`CHECK`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#constraints) constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Teacher_Table(
    Teacher_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    TFirst_Name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    TLast_Name VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
    Gender CHAR(1) NOT NULL CHECK (length(Gender) < 2),
    Home_Address VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    Contact_Number VARCHAR (14) NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: @IljaEverilä: yes, funny enough, MySQL ignores `CHECK`, making the "SQL landscape" quite chaotic :s.